# != in MySQL not working as I expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that worked fine, and then I wanted to add to the the existing where condition something like:
and some_column != 1

That column value was null.  But the query stopped finding the row it used to find.  Any idea why?

Thanks.
Alex

Comment: What does your query look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL in just about every form is notorious with its handling of null values in comparisons. If a column is nullable and you want to do a comparison on it, you should use ISNULL:

```
WHERE ISNULL(column_name, -1) != 0
```

That should take care of your problem.

Comment: I think `(column_name is null or column_name != 1)` would be more intuitive and probably would run faster.

Comment: @Malvolio - Performance-wise, there is going to be a negligible difference, if there is any at all. And more intuitive, I don't think so, but that's a purely subjective thing. I think that less code is far more intuitive than more code, and I have seen many people that truly don't understand OR in SQL correctly.

Comment: I did find Malvolio's solution to be more syntactically intuitive.  Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Charles-Boyung -- even a very simple optimizer could break the simple OR into two (indexed) queries, but it would take a much more sophisticated one to do the same with the ISNULL function.  Anyone who doesn't understand the OR should probably not be allowed near a computer or other electronic equipment.

Comment: It's not different than an OR in any other logical structure in other languages.  To be honest, ISNULL(column_name, -1) != 0 doesn't read very well to me at all.  When you say it out loud "Is null column name negative 1 not equal to 0"... or "column name is not null and column_name is not 1".  Second version makes far more sense.

Comment: @Charles-Boyung: @Malvolio is certainly right, at least in Microsoft SQL Server (and I strongly suspect in some other DBs as well). In database terms, (a is null or a = x) is a _sargable_ clause -- that is, a clause which can take advantage of a suitable covering index. The DB engine can probe the index twice; once for null, and once for value x, and then merge them together (or in the case of a != clause, use appropriate range queries to grab values above and below x). In contrast, most functions (like ISNULL) have to be evaluated row-by-row and hence trigger a scan, not seek, of the index.

Answer (score 2):

Almost any expression with null is null.  `1 != null` is UNKNOWN (and therefore would cause the row to be removed from the resultset). `1 = null` is UNKNOWN.  `1 + null` is UNKNOWN.

The most significant exception: `null is null` is TRUE.

Comment: but `null = null` evaluates to false

Comment: It certainly does.  Use `is`.

Answer (score 1):

NULL, by definition, is an "unknown value"... Therefore, null != 1 is an unknown result.  The NULL *might* be 1, and it might not be - but the key is that SQL will not attempt to guess.  This is sort of a weird way for SQL to handle the value, but it is what it is.

Therefore, if you want to account for possible nulls you need to change your where to this:

```
AND some_column != 1 AND some_column IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

using '<>' may work...can give a try

```
where ISNULL(coloumn_name,1) <> 1
```

Comment: ok, updated some..plz check...and for handling NULL value SQL is always messy